# Cut video with ffmpeg.

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cut

This is my idea.

I want to cut the first 10s of video and the last 10s of video

Thank for help

[image]

Comment: Is re-encoding the video ok?

Comment: yeah. thank Mulvya. can u help me?

Answer (score 5):

With re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[b][0]overlay=shortest=1" -shortest -c:a copy out.mp4
```

`-ss 10` sets the the amount to cut from beginning. `trim=10` sets amount to cut from end. Caveat here is that due to a current bug with `shortest=1`, this may not work on ffmpeg builds from 2017.

---

A bit of a hack method, which skips transcoding:

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i video.mp4 -ss 20 -i video.mp4 -c copy -map 1:0 -map 0 -shortest -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -map 0 -map -0:0 -c copy out.mp4
```

Depending on the location keyframes, the trims at start and end won't be perfect. First `ss` is starting trim. Second `ss` is `starting + ending` trim

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit nicer.

```
ffmpeg -i "<FILE>" -ss 00:00:10 -to  $( echo "$(ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "<FILE>") - 35"  | bc) -c copy  "trimmed-output.mp4"
```

this uses ffprobe to get the duration: `ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "<FILE>"`

and then pipes `<duration> - 10` to `bc` to subtract 10 from duration, which is then used in `-to` param on ffmpeg.